# How can we learn to classify images that are airplanes ?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, image-processing

The training set is a set of images of the airplanes. Task is : 
Given an image classify it as an airplane or not.
Is it feasible ?

Comment: Yes it is feasible. Have a look at one-class support vector machines, for example. (However, be ready to spend months on the project. Classifying images is not an easy task. Check book recommendations etc. for supervised learning from other questions.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is feasible. You have a bunch of tools in computer vision that can help you achieve this!

Usually, the first step is to represent your data through feature vectors, and then use a classifier on this training set to learn from your data.

For features, you might want to begin with HoG (*Histogram of oriented gradients*) features that will certainly be too naive to give great accuracy but will give you an insight of how you should proceed. You can complexify using Sift (Scale-invariant feature transform) features and why not merging them with HoGs. The huge advantage of Sifts is its invariance to usual transformations of pictures (scaling, rotating...). Then you should work a bit more with more specific feature extraction algorithm to reach a top accuracy - you might want to look at wavelets, scattering...

Once you have extracted relevant features from images, you have to chose a classifier. To begin with, I advise you something pretty easy - like logistic regression - that can help you determine relevant features - regularization path - and hence improve your features back. Once you have understood the geometry of your features you can try more complex transformations - kernel-SVM, e.g.

(One last option that I don't recommend because it is a bit tricky and does not explain data unless you're already an expert, is using deep learning technologies such as DBM (deep Boltzmann machines), DBN (deep belief networks)... The caveats from this is that you might do this without ever understanding the geometry of your data, just tricking parameters. Of course you might eventually have the best accuracy but you might end up with no more knowledge than before =) )